# Changing file name using multer in node JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multer, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to change the image name using ng-file-upload on client and multer as parser on node JS.

my server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './content/uploads/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
            //cb(null,"how are you" + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1]);
        }
 });

//multer settings
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('file');

/** API path that will upload the files */
app.post('/imageUpload',function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    })

});
app.get('/*',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Express node js server listening on port %d...", this.address().port);
});
```

my controller code:

```
uploadImagesApp.controller('HomeController',['$scope','uploadImageFactory','Upload','$window',function($scope,uploadImageFactory,Upload,$window){
    $scope.file;
    $scope.submitForm = function(form){ //function to call on form submit
        if (form.file.$valid && $scope.file) { //check if from is valid
            $scope.upload($scope.file); //call upload function
        }
    }

    $scope.upload = function (file) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/imageUpload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
            if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ //validate success
                $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ');
            } else {
                $window.alert('an error occured');
            }
        }, function (resp) { //catch error
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) { 
            console.log(evt);
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            $scope.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // capture upload progress
        });
    };
}]);
```

and my html view code:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm(uploadForm)" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm">
    <input type="text" name="fileName" id="image-name"/>
    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*' "accept="image/*" required/>
    Image thumbnail: <img style="width:100px;" ngf-thumbnail="file || '/thumb.jpg'"/>
    <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
    <p>{{progress}}</p>
</form>
```

i want to get in the file name in the form and send the image and the file name to node js.
but when im trying to use req.body.fileName i get undefined.
what is the correct way to do it so i will be able to pass the file name along with the image file?

Thank you.

Comment: At what point of the code you turn to `req.body.fileName`?

Comment: well i tried after calling upload and in the filename function and also before the calling for upload but in all those places req.body.filename was undifined

Comment: You can use `Upload.rename()` to rename the file on the client side with ng-file-upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just do not pass the required field when submitting the form. Try change:

*html view*:

```
<input type="text" name="fileName" id="image-name" ng-model="filename" required/>
```

*controller code*:

```
data:{file:file, filename: $scope.filename}
```

*server side*:

```
app.post('/imageUpload',function(req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        console.log(req.body.filename);
        if(err){
             res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
             return;
        }
         res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null});
    })    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/imageUpload',//webAPI exposed to upload the file
            fields: {
                newFileName: $scope.fileName
            },
            file: file
            //data:{file:file} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        })
```

the fields which i added gave me access to req.body.newFileName.

Thank you all for the help!